# Obtener id de un formulario creado anteriormente para relacionarlo a otra tabla LARAVEL 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

escribo por aca es porque tengo esta duda, a lo mejor es tonta pero no la he logrado solventar..

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas **REVISION** y **RIESGOS**, la relacion es **1 revision posee muchos riesgos**, y **1 riesgo pertenece a 1 revision**, ya hice la relacion en los modelos y en las bd, entonces ya en el formulario lo envio y se me guardan los datos, luego en otra pestaña  tengo un boton que me permite registrar un riesgo asociado a esta revision creada, pero no se **como obtener el id de la revision creada anteriormente**, cada formulario lo tengo en un controlador diferente ya que aparte de esa relacion hay una serie de opciones mas estan en RevisionController y RiesgoController respectivamente. No se si fui muy claro espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Algo así necesitas realizar para guardar el id de la revisión.

```
$model = New Revision;
$model->texto = $request->get('data');
if($model->save()){
    $riesgo = New Riesgo;
    $riesgo->id_revision = $model->id;
    $riesgo->data = $request->get('data');
    if($riesgo->save()){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: considerando que ambos se encuentran en controladores totalmente divorciados como aplicaria lo que me estas comentando , o crees que deberia tener un controlador para ambas cosas?

Comment: Sin problemas puedes hacerlo en el mismo controlador como recomendación si guardas datos en más de dos hablas utiliza un transaction por si ocurre algun error al momento de insertar los datos

Comment: ya tengo varias partes del codigo hechas, ya que hay otras cosas aparte de la relacion de las id, como implementaria eso que me indicas teniendo en cuenta que son dos controladores